# Stateful Drawer Content in Scaffold Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, stateful, scaffold

Can I change the content of drawer in a scaffold? I have a drawer and I have a text in its header to change. For example whenever a user logs in, I want the text in this drawer's header to change. But the drawer content is not recomposing just the scaffoldState.drawerState.open() open/close the drawer.